formmating my paper{the frame}
I hope you all right. so my problem is I want to make a frame for my paper like that:
if anyone know the full step-by-step Please, reply to me. And Thank You!

This perhaps is a special footer style. Try the fancyhdr package.

BTW: [tag:overleaf] is not a suitable tag just because you are using Overleaf. You should not use it for general LaTeX questions. See the tag description. Always try to search for more relevant tags. This would also help you to find relevant other questions.

For the magenta(?) line you could, e.g., use [tag:tikz-pgf]. This could also be used to draw the other elements. More easy would be, if the other or all elements would be available as image and could be included using [tag:graphics].
